# Cloudfront CORS access issue

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I was trying to access my s3 assets through cloudfront, and I made this ajax request and passing in those set-cookie headers.

I'm able to generate a signed url and it totally works fine, but what I really want to do is using the signed cookies method to access the resources.

Following is my testing code, but that I got is **403** ( and then No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. )

```
function getCookie(name)
{
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? decodeURIComponent(value[1]) : null;
}

// I try to use XMLHttpRequest
// ---------------------------------------------
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", 'http://a_cloudfront_url/mystuff.json', false);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Set-Cookie", "Domain=my_domain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Expires="+getCookie('CloudFront-Expires'));
oReq.setRequestHeader("Set-Cookie", "Domain=my_domain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id="+getCookie('CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id'));
oReq.setRequestHeader("Set-Cookie", "Domain=my_domain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Signature="+getCookie('CloudFront-Signature'));
oReq.send();

// I also try to use the jquery ways
// ---------------------------------------------
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://a_cloudfront_url/mystuff.json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Set-Cookie", "Domain=my_domain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Expires="+getCookie('CloudFront-Expires'));
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Set-Cookie", "Domain=my_domain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id="+getCookie('CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id'));
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Set-Cookie", "Domain=my_domain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Signature="+getCookie('CloudFront-Signature'));
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log('Error',e);
    }
});
```

But all give me 403 only ...

**the following is my response headers look like ...**

```
// The following is my response header
// ---------------------------------------------
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:146
Content-Type:text/xml
Date:Tue, 19 May 2015 19:22:04 GMT
Server:CloudFront
Via:1.1 blah-blah.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:GNQKtum1Rz4eblah-blahWqGQXPOtowD1ZrBbIAx6aGB0j_AMbA==
X-Cache:Error from cloudfront
```

**the following is my request headers look like ...**

```
// The following is my request header
// ---------------------------------------------
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:set-cookie
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:my_cloud_front_doman.cloudfront.net
Origin:http://my_domain.com
Referer:http://my_domain.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4)
```

**Any help is appreciated. I talk with the Amazon reps, they said the clouldfront configuration are setup correctly, I wonder if there is anything wrong with my code.**

Comment: Well, did you do anything to enable CORS?

Comment: can you give us full details about the headers sent across the wire ?

Comment: @CBroe,  yes, I do, and I even have the Amazon team to review our cloudfront configuration.

Comment: @Marged, I will update the request header in the question.

Comment: There is simply no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header present in the response – so you will have to check your configuration again.

Comment: I think it is the reasons ----> Most Browsers will not allow cookies or any header values to be set in a Preflight OPTIONS request for a CORS asset  ( for security reason ).  And when the request hit the cloudfront distribution, it doesn't see the auth cookie, so it return 403.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting answer to my own question, hope it helps other people :)

At the end, I try to set up a CNAME alias for my cloudfront domain. And from this point on, I can set the cookies on the base domain, then you will be able to pass your cookie.

Let's put more detail to it in case people want to know what would be the next step is, let's use the following example :-

1. You are developing on **my.fancy.site.mydomain.com**
2. Your Cloudfront CNAME is **content.mydomain.com**
3. Make sure you set your cloudfront signed cookies to **.mydomain.com** from your fancy app
4. From this point on, you are able to pass the cookie for the CF.
5. One quick way to test if your cookie is set appropriately, try to get your assets URL, and put the url in the browser directly.  If the cookie set correctly, you will be able to access the file directly.

If you are using javascript to get the cdn assets, make sure in your JS code, you need to pass withCredentials option, or it won't work.  For example, if you are using jQuery, you will need something like the following :-

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

And if the request is successful, you should get a response header from CloudFront with "Access-Control-blah-blah".

Hope it helps people if they search this answer.